# Partial Type Mapping in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a JSON with lots of data. Now all the fields does not have fixed types of data every time. For example some `Ids` are some time appearing as perfect integer, like `123`, but some time it appears as `String`, like `a123`.

By default, `index.mapper.dynamic` is `true`. So type mapping is automatically defined as per data received for first time for indexing `(While creating the index for first set of JSON data)`. Now let's say, my first set of data is having `Id` value as `123`, so type of `Id` is mapped as `Integer`. So when some data have `Id` as `String`, like `a123`, then it is throwing exception, as the type is mapped to `Integer`.

We can turn off dynamic type mapping by putting`index.mapper.dynamic: false` in `elasticsearch.yml`. But it will disable type mapping for all fields. I want to have `Partial Type Mapping`. For some fields, like `date`, I would like to have type mapping for `datetime` in specific format.

So my goal is to achieve type mapping only for few fields of JSON data. So if there are 20 fields in JSON, I bother for types of 4 fields, for other 16 fields if they are considered as String, I am OK with that.

Is there any way I can achieve such partial type mapping ? I am using Java client.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no.

A bit longer - ElasticSearch is not schema-less - it's dynamic. It means that **every field has a type**, but this type doesn't need to be specified in advance but can be dynamically determined according to the first value which is encountered.
But again - there is no such thing as a field with no mapping. You can't have a field that contains different types of values. 
If this is something you must have you can just convert all the values of this field to string.